# How to use history commands with readonly PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc, readonly

I'm sometimes logged in on a host which I do not control and where `PROMPT_COMMAND` is `readonly`. Is there some way to **work around this to run [`history` commands](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/8665ca0af87bdbf6dd577e90908e77726fe7bdf5/.bashrc#L12-17) anyway**, for example using `PS1`? I've tried `PS1='$(history -a; history -c; history -r; echo finished)'` - It prints `finished` at each prompt, but it doesn't seem to work:

1. Open two terminals A and B on the same host.
2. In terminal A, run a command `a`.
3. In terminal B, run a command `b`.
4. It terminal B, press <kbd>↑</kbd> twice.

On a host where `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -c; history -r;'`, this will result in terminal B showing `a`. On a host where `PS1` starts with `$(history -a; history -c; history -r; echo finished)` it will instead show whichever command was run before both terminals were opened. The obvious reason is that **the command in `PS1` is run in a subshell.**

Another alternative is to bypass the global RC-file altogether:

```
bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc
```

However, circumventing the use of the standard value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` will very likely *not be accepted by the sysadmin* for policy reasons.

Comment: You can work around a readonly var by spawning a new shell, with an alternate rc file.

Comment: @jordanm Good point, updated the question.

Comment: @jw013 I have lots of command substitutions in `PS1` which work, but this one has to update the state of the parent shell, which is probably not possible.

Comment: @l0b0 You are right about the subshell. But maybe you can use another hack... What exactly is the value of your `$PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: I can't really tell you what the standard value is on the host in question, but my own is in [my public .bashrc](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/8665ca0af87bdbf6dd577e90908e77726fe7bdf5/.bashrc#L12-17).

Comment: I don't get it - how will changing `PROMPT_COMMAND` prompt a negative reaction from the sysadmin?  What if you run a shell that doesn't even have a `PROMPT_COMMAND`, like `sh`?  What if you typed all your commands into a file and ran them through a non-interactive `bash` instance?  Are you saying you are not allowed to do any of those things?

Comment: @jw013 Presumably the `PROMPT_COMMAND` is doing some kind of logging by policy. ＠l0b0 Would the admins object to your using zsh if you supplied a `precmd` that's similar to their `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: Seems like `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a silly place to do logging.  Aren't there more robust methods?  What if the prompt command logged nothing but `vi foo; . ./foo; rm foo` all day?  What about `ssh` remote commands?  Then the sysadmin "objects" and boots the user off the system?  If so, sounds like a BOFH to me.

Comment: Please. I'd rather discuss the technical issue.

Comment: @l0b0 Sorry, but I don't understand. You mean the value of `COMMAND_PROMPT` on the host in question needs to be kept confidential?

Comment: @l0b0 The technical issue has been solved - get a non-readonly `PROMPT_COMMAND` by running a new shell.  Ignoring real-life when making technical decisions is a recipe for outrageous setups.  Sounds like you have much deeper non-technical problems if you can't even run a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the history commands in a signal handler, avoiding the use of a subshell.  Then have `PS1` send the appropriate signal:

```
trap 'history -a; history -c; history -r;' USR1
export PS1='$(kill -USR1 $$)'"$PS1"
```